# Why is my variable not iterating in this foreach loop?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a div ID have a unique name by using a variable to iterate through the number of times it gets looped.  For some reason my $k variable doesn't seem to be advancing.  Here is the code:

```
<?php foreach($files as $media)
                { 
                    $k = 0;
                    ?>
                    <h3><?php echo $output[$j] ?></h3>
                    <div id='mediaspace<?php echo $k ?>'>This text will be replaced</div>

                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                      ...
                      so.write('mediaspace<?php echo $k ?>');
                    </script>
                <?php 
                $k = $k+1;
                } ?>
```

My HTML output just gives me a 0 for $k every time the loop is run:

```
<div id='mediaspace0'>This text will be replaced</div>


                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                     ...                  so.write('mediaspace0');
                    </script>
                                        <h3>Rattletree Marimba Day</h3>
                    <div id='mediaspace0'>This text will be replaced</div>

                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                      ...                 so.write('mediaspace0');
                    </script>
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course:

```
$k = 0;
```

Reset the variable **before** the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
$k = 0;
```

at the start of the loop resets your `$k` to `0` *at the start of each iteration*.

Move it outside the loop:

```
<?php 
$k = 0;
foreach($files as $media)
{ 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting $k to 0 at the begining of your foreach.

Set it outside.

```
$k = 0;
foreach($files as $media) {
...
```